# Can raphaeljs shapes be transformed into one another?

Tags: path, raphael, transform, shapes

I have one shape

```
var a = paper.rect(10,10,50,20);
```

I want to transform this shape into

```
var b = paper.circle(10,10,20);
```

Is there any way to transform these inbuilt shapes into one another. I know paths can be transformed anyhow you want them to but can shapes also be transformed?

Comment: i believe you can! in this example the share is being transformed http://raphaeljs.com/curver.html

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain properly.
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kzpp/) . Initially I have drawn a rectangle using path and then it transforms into a circle path.

Now I want to achieve this without using paths. I want to transform the rect shape directly into circle shape. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, except if you simply fade out one shape and fade in the other one. The reason for this is that at some point in time during the conversion the shape is neither a rectangle nor a circle, while any single animated shape in SVG has to remain the same kind of shape throughout the animation, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have to do it using paths then.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this if with a little creativity.  A rectangle can be a circle if width, height and r (radius) are all the same.  Then transforming a rect to a "circle" becomes:

`p=Raphael(10, 50, 600, 300);
myrect=p.rect(50,50, 300,150,0).attr({"fill":"cyan"});
myrect.animate({"width":25,"height":25, "r":25}, 3000);`

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s1pz6Lzc/30/

Comment: The code above worked.   However, I believe the the "r" value should be half the height/width.  So if height=25 and width=25 then r=12.5.  jsfiddle has it working with r as 25, but I noticed some problems in older IE.